# Getting ModuleNotFound error when deploying a gunicorn flask app in Cloud Run (works locally or in docker-compose)

Tags: docker, flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I've been struggling with a strange issue. Deploying a gunicorn simple python flask API to Cloud Run consistenly gives me a ModuleNotFound error:

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEpbw.png)

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV PORT 8080
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app .

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 4 server:app
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpOGC.png)

```
- database-api
  - app
     configuration.py
     util.py
     server.py
  Dockerfile
  requirement.txt
  cloudbuild.yaml
```

[Cloudbuild yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyMfm.png)

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '-t'
  - 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/database-api:$TAG_NAME'
  - '-f'
  - './Dockerfile'
  - '.'

images:
- 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/database-api:$TAG_NAME'
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oJdE.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 95, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'
```

When running the docker file locally (manualy or through docker-compose) everything works without issues.

When I deploy it to Cloud Run initially there is no error, but once I add a volume mount with a secret (path /app/conf.json) and an environment variable in the service and try to call it I see the error pop up. I can't figure out if this is related or just a coincidence.

I've tried everything I can think of - changing the paths, adding 'chdir' to gunicorn call, changing the folder structure, giving the module as app.server, completely recreating the service, using different python or package versions, changing the name of the module to 'app' instead of 'server', etc. Nothing works.
When I add debug prints in the docker file I can see that the folder is correct (/app) and the files are there (configuration.py, util.py, server.py). I also tried placing the **init**.py inside the folder as well, in case that was missing. There is no dockerignore or gitignore to remove anything unexpectedly.

No google searches, docs or other questions seem to have the same problem. I also checked other projects that use the exact same folder structure and dockerfile and they work. A [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-a-python-flask-server-using-google-cloud-run-d47f728cc864) I found also shows the exact same process without any issues. Everything I can find shows that my implementation should work, as I can test myself locally. It only breaks when I deploy to Cloud Run after the cloudbuild.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: You don't include the Cloud Run deployment. I suspect (!) you're overwriting your container's `/app` folder (which contains `server:app`) when you do the volume mount.

Comment: You mention that everything works without Volume Mount but you do not show the command that you used for the Volume Mount. I guess that the app folder has been replaced by the Volume Mount.

Comment: God I feel silly... you are both absolutely right! I was mounting the volume through the gcloud UI and was indeed overwriting my /app folder... thank you so much for saving my sanity, sometimes its the small things we overlook that deafeat us I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As DazWilkin and John Hanley pointed out - it turned out that my Volume Mount was the issue. It was overwriting the /app folder. Simply changing my mount path from /app/conf.json to /conf/conf.json in the Cloud Run service did the trick. It also didnt help that I was attaching the Volume Mount through the UI (meaning only doing it once during the setup of the service instead of every revision deployment through the CLI command) so it was easier to miss.

Hope this helps anyone who ends up in the same situation.

Comment: Can you share the solution that you are now using?

Comment: I simply changed the mount path in UI from /app to /conf. Will work on changing my deploy script to add the full service description and update the answer here tomorrow.